# Javascript - Handle Promise Error from Function that Does Not Exist

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a weird situation where I need to check the value of a function inserted by a user, ideally with a promise that returns an error if the user inserts a function that does not exist. I was thinking something along these lines:

```
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  var customVar = customClass.userSelected(1, 2);

  if (customVar) {
    console.log("Success!");
    resolve(data);
  } else {
    console.log("Failure!");
    reject(err);
  }

});
```

where `userSelected` is what the user has inserted. But of course this give can give me a "`userSelected` is not a function" if they have inserted something that is not a method of the customClass. Is there proper way to check for this with promises or do I just need to do a check with a switch statement or something similar instead?

Comment: Why do you need a promise for synchronous stuff???

Comment: Are you generating code from user input? How does the user give you the `userSelected` part? (Also: What's `data`"? It appears out of nowhere...)

Comment: And did you mean `someClass[userSelected]()` ?

Comment: The idea is to run a test using promises based off the user input. And I do not know how it will be given yet. Trying to get ahead of the curve.

Comment: `userSelected` is what? How is it defined.... Show code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any need for promises here, but getting to the thrust of your question:

Let's assume you have `input`, a variable containing the function name you got from the user (perhaps it's `"foo"`). You can make sure it exists on `customClass` by checking for it:

```
if (typeof customClass[input] === "function") {
    // Yes, it's a function
}
```

There, if `input` is `"foo"`, you know `customClass` has a property called `foo` whose value is a function.

So if we plug that into your example (but again, I don't see why we'd need a promise for this):

```
var input = /*...the function name from the user...*/
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  if (typeof customClass[input] !== "function") {
    reject(new Error(input + " is not a valid method"));
  } else try {
    resolve(customClass[input](1, 2));
  } catch (e) {
    reject(new Error(input + " failed with an error: " + e.message));
  }
});
```

Note that we don't have to catch the exception from calling the method if we don't want to provide a custom error for it; an error throw in a promise executor function rejects the promise. So if you want to just allow the original error to be the rejection:

```
var input = /*...the function name from the user...*/
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  if (typeof customClass[input] !== "function") {
    reject(new Error(input + " is not a valid method"));
  } else {
    resolve(customClass[input](1, 2));
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't know, I upvoted and accepted lol. Thanks for showing me a better way to do this!